# VBO = glGenBuffers() IllegalStateException

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, vbo, eclipse

i'm kinda noob in OpenGL but I have this problem: I get an IllegalStateException at this code:

```
int vboVertex = glGenBuffers();
```

In-detail exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Function is not supported
at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkFunctionAddress(BufferChecks.java:58)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL15.glGenBuffers(GL15.java:116)
at Mesh.initVbo(Mesh.java:49)
```

OpenGL version: 
2.0.5819 WinXP Release

Thanks for support and sorry for the horrible english.

Comment: You might need some extension loading library to validate the opengl function pointers?

Comment: You also might need to update your OpenGL driver, it looks like you are using an OpenGL 1.5 path, which stinks like the Microsoft implementation.

Comment: @MickLH: If the version string is to be believed, he has an OpenGL 2.0-era driver. Even though it might not support all (or even any) of the required OpenGL 2.0 extensions it's supposed to (compliance back then was hit or miss) VBOs were widely available even before OpenGL 1.5 made them mandatory. In any event, never trust the version string for anything :P My money's on the extension procedure addresses are not being loaded, but I have no idea how that is done in Java.

Comment: Well that's the thought I was on too, but from the backtrace alone it looks as if there is a system in place for loading the functions. Anyways, for something concrete lets see if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) == false, if so it explains everything and provides an answer of "update your shit".

Comment: (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) is true. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring your development environment.